# How to include the volume number in IEEE conference reference?

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran

I want to include the volume number in my IEEE conference reference and use the code in the following

```
@inproceedings{Logue2001, 
author = "Logue, D.L. and Krein, P.T.", 
title = "Preventing instability in DC distribution systems by using power buffering", 
booktitle = "Proc. IEEE Power Electronics Specialists Conference", 
volume = "1",
month = jun,
year = "2001", 
pages = "33-37"}
```

The output is like:

> D. Logue and P. Krein, “Preventing instability in dc distribution systems by using power buffering,” in Proc. IEEE Power Electronics Specialists Conference, **vol. 1, Jun. 2001**, pp. 33–37.

However, I would like the output to be

> D. Logue and P. Krein, “Preventing instability in dc distribution systems by using power buffering,” in Proc. IEEE Power Electronics Specialists Conference, **Jun. 2001, vol. 1**, pp. 33–37.

The volume number should appear after the month and year. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: The entry at hand is of type `@inproceedings`. As such, the information `vol. 1` definitely should be placed *immediately after* the `booktitle` field. If I'd change anything, I would render `vol. 1` in italic rather than in upright letters, to emphasize its association with the title of the conference series title. I definitely wouldn't exchange the order of the volume number and the date string.

Comment: By the way, you should place curly braces around the snippet "DC" in the title field in order to prevent BibTeX from changing it to "dc". I.e., you should write `... instability in {DC} distribution ...`. Also, do introduce space between the abbreviated first names, i.e., write the field as `author = "Logue, D. L. and Krein, P. T.",`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit the associated `.bst` file and adjust the `inproceedings` FUNCTION to match the sequence in the output. Since you're using [`IEEEtran`](http://ctan.org/pkg/IEEEtran), we're talking about [`IEEEtran.bst`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtran.bst). Here's the entry in question:

```
FUNCTION {inproceedings}
{ std.status.using.comma
  start.entry
  if.url.alt.interword.spacing
  format.authors "author" output.warn
  name.or.dash
  format.article.title "title" output.warn
  format.in.booktitle "booktitle" output.warn
  format.series output
  format.editors output
  format.volume output
  format.number output
  publisher empty$
    { format.address.organization.date output }
    { format.organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
      format.address.publisher.date output
    }
  if$
  format.paper output
  format.pages output
  format.note output
  format.url output
  fin.entry
  if.url.std.interword.spacing
}
```

Note how `*.date` (within `publisher`) *follows* `*.volume`. If you flip these around, they will be updated in the output as well. So your new `inproceedings` FUNCTION should resemble:

```
FUNCTION {inproceedings}
{ std.status.using.comma
  start.entry
  if.url.alt.interword.spacing
  format.authors "author" output.warn
  name.or.dash
  format.article.title "title" output.warn
  format.in.booktitle "booktitle" output.warn
  format.series output
  format.editors output
  publisher empty$
    { format.address.organization.date output }
    { format.organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
      format.address.publisher.date output
    }
  if$
  format.volume output
  format.number output
  format.paper output
  format.pages output
  format.note output
  format.url output
  fin.entry
  if.url.std.interword.spacing
}
```

You can save this new `IEEEtran.bst` in your working folder. Here is a complete minimal example with the new output following the compile sequence (pdf)LaTeX > BibTeX > (pdf)LaTeX > (pdf)LaTeX:

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{Logue2001, 
  author = "Logue, D. L. and Krein, P. T.", 
  title = "Preventing instability in {DC} distribution systems by using power buffering", 
  booktitle = "Proc. IEEE Power Electronics Specialists Conference", 
  volume = "1",
  month = jun,
  year = "2001", 
  pages = "33-37"}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

<sub>Don't change journal styles, since they'll change it back to their requirements.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

If you want to consider using `biblatex-ieee`, it's easy with the `xpatch` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = ieee]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibdriver{inproceedings}{%
 \usebibmacro{volume+part}%
 \newunit
 \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
}
{%
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{volume+part}%
}{}{}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{Logue2001,
author = "Logue, D.L. and Krein, P.T.",
title = "Preventing instability in DC distribution systems by using power buffering",
booktitle = "Proc. IEEE Power Electronics Specialists Conference",
volume = "1",
month = jun,
year = "2001",
pages = "33-37"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]